# Canvas React. Is there a better way to call a function multiple images onload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

Here is part of my React code. It works with canvas.

```
    componentDidMount(){                
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");     
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    
            ctx.fillStyle="#000";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,2800,2800);
            ctx.fillStyle="#eee";
            ctx.fillRect(150,150,2500,2500);        
            var board = this.generateBoard(ctx);     
            var createImage = function(src){
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = src;
                return img;
            }   
            var images = {
                "hero-right": createImage("../../images/hero-right.png"),
                "hero-left": createImage("../../images/hero-left.png"),
                "treasure": createImage("../../images/treasure.png")
            };        
            var imageCount = Object.keys(images).length;        
            var imagesLoaded = 0;

            for(var key in images){            
                images[key].onload = function(){
                    imagesLoaded++;                
                    if(imagesLoaded == imageCount){                    
                        startGame();
                    }
                };
            }

            var startGame = function(){            
                this.setState({
                        ctx: ctx,
                        board: board,
                        hero:{
                            img: images["hero-right"],
                            x: 0,
                            y:0
                        }            
                    },
                    ()=>{this.placeItems()}
                );
            }.bind(this)          
        },

        placeItems(){
            this.placeHero();
        },
```

The problem was - I need to call this piece of code:

```
           this.setState({
                    ctx: ctx,
                    board: board,
                    hero:{
                        img: images["hero-right"],
                        x: 0,
                        y:0
                    }            
                },
                ()=>{this.placeItems()}
            );
```

after all of my images loaded.
I managed to do that. But it's ugly. Please help me to make it better.

Comment: Similar question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534549/how-do-you-deal-with-html5s-canvas-image-load-asynchrony

Comment: great! I will try that approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you deal with html5's canvas image load asynchrony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534549/how-do-you-deal-with-html5s-canvas-image-load-asynchrony)

Comment: so 12 months ago