# Images not loading to canvas with context.drawImage() in JS - Tile based Game

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a tile-map in JavaScript/HTML with canvas. I am using two .png image files of 55 x 55 pixels for the grass and water textures.

The tiles for this game are not loading in the canvas during the arrays 'for loops'. both image files are in the same folder level as the .html page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mapArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var grass = new Image();
var water = new Image();

grass.src = 'grass_tile.png';
water.src = 'water_tile.png';

var posX = 0;
var PosY = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
    if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
      context.drawImage(grass, posX, PosY, 55, 55);
    }
    if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
      context.drawImage(water, posX, PosY, 55, 55);
    }
    posX += 55;
  }
  posX = 0;
  posY += 55;
}
```

```css
<style>#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!doctype <!document html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GAME</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="520px" width="520px"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it `posY` or `PosY`? I'm assuming one is a typo - but does this typo exist in your original code too?

Comment: You have to wait for the images to load before you can draw them

Comment: Thanks Robin, quite right on the typo for posY.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, since there are two tiles can you suggest the best way to handle the **onload**? I have found examples for waiting for one image to load, but not sure how I would input this for two images within the context of the for loop.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534549/how-do-you-deal-with-html5s-canvas-image-load-asynchrony/34534753#34534753) for loading/waiting for multiple images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points here:

1. You forgot to place commas in your multidimensional array.
2. Some places you have the var `PosY`, and in other places you have `posY`.
3. You should wait for your images to be loaded in order to draw them.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var mapArray = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

var grass = new Image();
var water = new Image();

grass.src = 'https://fyldegrass.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Lytham-Ebay-Top2-128x128.jpg';
water.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';


var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;

grass.onload = function () { draw(); };


function draw() {
  for (var i = 0; i < mapArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < mapArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 0) {
        context.drawImage(grass, posX, posY, 55, 55);
      }
      if (mapArray[i][j] == 1) {
        context.drawImage(water, posX, posY, 55, 55);
      }
      posX += 55;
    }
    posX = 0;
    posY += 55;
  }
}
```

```css
<style>#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!doctype <!document html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GAME</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="520px" width="520px"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked...my first post and I'm blown away by the help and the speed of replies. Apologies all for the typos, but thank you for taking the time to point them out, couldn't see the wood for the trees after 2 days trying to get this to work.